# Show wait dialog on long running change event

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox with a change event. When there is many data, the click on the checkbox does some background task which can take some time.

So the first thing I do is:

```
$chxSelectAll.on('change', function (e) {
            $('.loadingnew').show()
            ... Long running code here
}
```

The problem is: The waiting spinner is only shown, when the change event completed the code. The code works outside or from console without problem. How can I force the show() before the code is running?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The waiting spinner is only shown, when the change event completed the code.

That means that the long-running task *isn't* in the background, it's in the foreground, tying up (blocking) the thread that's shared by the JavaScript code and the page display code.

You have two choices:

1. If possible, offload the long-running task to a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) thread, so it's not running on the main UI thread, blocking page updates.
2. If that isn't possible, delay the start of the blocking code for about 60ms using `setTimeout`, so the browser has a chance to show the "loading" spinner before the code holds up the thread. Beware that the spinner may well not actually spin, but it will at least be visible.

Here's an example of #2:

```
$chxSelectAll.on('change', function (e) {
    $('.loadingnew').show()
    setTimeout(() => {
        ... Long running code here
    }, 60);
});
```

Comment: Instead of a hard setTimeout, perhaps rAF would work too? Just to defer the long running code to the next paint. Otherwise, OP might want to consider using web workers to offload the task.

Comment: @Terry - Yeah, I've done that too, but it's more complicated because you have to trigger a `setTimeout` from within the `requestAnimationFrame`, since the rAF runs before the page is painted. (Basically, `requestAnimationFrame(() => setTimeout(() => { /*...*/ }, 0); };`) Also, even doing that, I had trouble with Firefox and had to include a hardcoded delay anyway. 60ms is (from experience) reliable when done in response to a user action (such as a click) and is simpler, so that's what I tend to do.

Comment: I used the setTimeout, works fine for my needs